# How can I able to apply hover class to any element without applying changes to parent elements?

Tags: javascript, css

For example I have HTML like this:

```
html > body > section > p > span > i
html > body > aside > ul > li > span
...
```

I want to apply hover style without writing hover each node one by one and when I hovered it should hover only child element but not parent one.

I'm capturing the element once the user clicks it. I want to visually show the user which specific element they will capture before they click any element. That's why I need hover to any element inside html.

So far I tried js `mouseenter` `mouseleave` and CSS `*` but both of them hovering along with parent node.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear what you want to do or what you've tried. If you target the `span` with CSS and use `:hover`, it will only apply those styles when the `span` is hovered, not when the ancestor elements are ([example](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-question-61747432-w202d?file=/index.html)). Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: Hovering over a child will also hover over the parent since the child is part of the parent. Describe what your actual problem / goal is and maybe we can help you. Are you asking how to disable the hover effect for the parent while the mouse is also hovering the child? Is this for some kind of editing platform where you want to let the user select something?

Comment: Perhaps use a [mouseover event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event) and prevent bubbling.

Comment: @ChrisG currently I'm capturing element once it clicks to any element. I want to visually show user which specific element they will capture before they click any element. That's why I need hover to any element inside html

Comment: @Shaxrillo - Ah! I get what you're trying to do now...

Comment: I typed it up so I'm going to post it :) https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/9gsf2b51/

Comment: @ChrisG - Purdy! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with `mouseover`, here's an example (see comments):

```js
// Listen for `mouseover`
document.body.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
    // I'm displaying the path in an element with id="path", so ignore that
    if (event.target.id === "path") {
        // Ignore it
        return;
    }
    // Get the element we've most recently highlighted
    const active = document.querySelector(".active");
    // If it's not the same as the target...
    if (active !== event.target) {
        // Remove the highlight from the old element
        if (active) {
            active.classList.remove("active");
        }

        // Show the path of the target
        let path = description(event.target);
        for (let el = event.target.parentElement; el; el = el.parentElement) {
            path = description(el) + " > " + path;
        }
        document.getElementById("path").textContent = path;

        // Add highlight to the new target
        event.target.classList.add("active");
    }
});

function description(el) {
    return el.tagName +
        (el.id ? "#" + el.id : "") +
        (el.className ? "." + el.className.replace(/ /g, ".") : "");
}
```

```css
.active {
    background-color: yellow;
}
#path {
    min-height: 1em;
    border-bottom; 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="path"></div>
<section>
    <p>
        This is a paragraph
        <span>span inside the paragraph</span>
    </p>
</section>
<aside>
    This is an aside
    <ul id="list" class="foo">
        <li>
            This is a list item
            <span class="nifty">span inside the list item</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</aside>
```

The yellow background just a placeholder for whatever form of indicator you want to show.

Comment: You might want to edit the question so it makes sense and is consistent with the answer… ;-)

Comment: @RobG - I copied (an edited version of) the OP's clarifying comment into the question a while ago, that seemed sufficient...?

Comment: I think it's the title that had me confused, maybe the first sentence of the question should be the title? It wasn't until I read your answer that I got what the OP wanted to do.